# Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') while running react code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, visual-studio-code

Trying to run a code on React which sends post request using express.While running it it shows this error. How can i solve it?

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34502:45)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:83767:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:83212:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:83424:21)
    at ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33770:11)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:83767:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:83212:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:83424:21)
    at ./node_modules/express/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33107:18)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:83767:31)
```

Comment: it's telling you the variable which you are trying to access is undefined, show us the code